# Controlling relay over 433MHz transmitter from RPi 3

Tags: pi-3, gpio, python

I am currently learning the usage of GPIO pins on my Raspberry Pi 3.

I have now a basic understanding of how to control the GPIO pins via Python, I am able to light up a LED, capture a button press or control a relay.

I bought this [bundle](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/5sets-NiceRF-Free-Shipping-433Mhz-ASK-Transmitter-Module-STX882-And-Receiver-Module-SRX882-TX-module-RX/1999770361.html?spm=a2g0s.9042311.0.0.fI2s1a) on AliExpress which contains STX882 (transmitter) and SRX882 (receiver).

Now, I would like to remotely control (from my RPi) a 3V relay which should then, after being turned on, control a valve to my garden watering.

I understand how to connect the STX882 transmitter to Raspberry and send data though the GPIO pins but I do not know, how to assemble the other side with the receiver. I have a problem understanding how these two pieces (transmitter connected to RPi and receiver connected to the relay) are paired to each other and what data to send to the receiver to turn the relay on.

Thank you for your tips.

Comment: *"how to assemble the other side with the receiver"* -> You need something to interpret the signal from the receiver and trigger the relay when required.  You can't simply hook the receiver up to the relay.

Comment: what could this interpreter be? I only need 0/1 to switch the relay on or off

Comment: I'm no expert -- you might want to ask about the possibilities on our larger sibling site, [Electrical Engineering](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/).  However, to make a semi-educated guess, I'd say either a fairly complex custom circuit (or there may be integrated circuits around already for this purpose), a programmable microcontroller (you can get an arduino nano clone for ~$5), or another dev board.  The ESP8266 also comes to mind, in which case you might as well ditch the radios.  Probably the arduino is the best bet.

Comment: You need to enable the receiver by setting cs pin to HIGH before you can get any output from the Data (output) on the receiver and use it to control a relay or a transistor (to drive the relay). I would suggest that you use a relay shield than connecting directly to the relay.

Comment: for testing, use an LED at receiver instead of a relay.   ........ i think that the receiver output mirrors the transmitter input .... so it's like a long wire

Comment: I like the comparison to a long wire, thanks. But, how do I pair the transmitter and the receiver? Say I have 3 pairs of them, each transmitter controlling a different receiver.. am I able to tweak the frequency a bit so each pair communicates at own frequency?